# MySQL order: put rows matching something on top of query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query that gets users with a certain age. E.G `AGE <= 5`

So the query gets these rows:

```
Country | Age
US        5
US        20
AR        3
ES        5
US        2
```

The problem is that to remain relevant I want to display the results matching the user's country first, using US as an example it should be like this:

```
Country | Age
US        2
US        5
US        20
US        2
AR        3
ES        5
```

I know how to do this with two queries, first getting US results and then the rest and order all by age but I wanted to know if it's possible to get results ordered with just one query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an ORDER BY like this:

```
order by case country when 'US' then 1 else 2 end, country, age
```

That would put US first and then the rest would come after and be sorted by `country`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that your table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE tblName
(
   country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   age INT NOT NULL
)
```

Then you can do the following query to purpose your requirements.

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE age <= 5 ORDER BY (country='US') DESC, age
```